# Recursive query mysql

Tags: mysql, hierarchy, recursive-query

I am not able to get recursive data with a query that uses this statement:

`WITH RECURSIVE`

I'm trying to get the rows related on the table:

```
id |      name     |extern|
--------------------------|
1  |  building_01  |  null
--------------------------|
2  |    floor_01   |  1
--------------------------|
3  |    zone_04    |  2
--------------------------|
4  |    zone_05    |  3
```

I need to get this data: where are zone_05 ?

```
4 | zone_05    | 3
---------------|
3 | zone_04    | 2
---------------|
2 | floor_01   | 1
---------------|
1 | building_01| null
---------------|
```

I'm trying to solve it with this statement, but I only get the first related row :

```
select  id,
    name,
    extern
    from    (select * from table) products_sorted,
    (select @pv := '4') initialisation
    where   find_in_set(id, @pv) > 0
    and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', extern)
```

Result:

```
4 | zone_05    | 3
---------------|
3 | zone_04    | 2
---------------|
```

This solution is not working for me :

[How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

@trincot Would it be possible to alter this to work in "reverse"? So grab all of a rows parents, grandparents, etc? I've used your first query for getting descendants but I would like to get the ancestors? as well. – shreddish Jul 19 '17 at 14:54

if anyone else was looking for the answer to the question @shreddish asked, the solution is to change on p.parent_id = cte.id to on p.id = cte.parent_id – fanfare Dec 10 '17 at 5:38

The solution is related to :

Alternative 1: WITH RECURSIVE, CONNECT BY

and I'm not able to use it because mysql database server version.

Comment: First of all add a correct layout for questions, maybe this help you to achieve some answer. And try also to add data model, to understand a little bit the problem.

Comment: Are you on mysql 8 or above?

Comment: Here the version of mysql database server: # Variable_name, Value
'innodb_version', '1.1.8'
'protocol_version', '10'
'slave_type_conversions', ''
'version', '5.5.19-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log'
'version_comment', 'MySQL Enterprise Server - Advanced Edition (Commercial)'
'version_compile_machine', 'x86_64'
'version_compile_os', 'Linux'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: Care to explain the relevance of JPA here? You post no use of JPA API

Comment: I'm working on a app using jpa and creating named Query with Entity Manager but for this use I think there are not any solution. So I'm trying with m.createNativeQuery(sql String). No relevance. Deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query that you need;

```
select  id,
        name,
        extern_id 
from    (select * from places
         order by id desc, extern_id desc) places_sorted,
        (select @pv := '26') initialisation
where   find_in_set(id, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', extern_id)
```

This is the fiddle: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba5700/2

As you can see, the "order by" is important as explained by trincot in the answer that you mention

Comment: Take into account that this only works if id>id_extern (as trincot explains in the linked answer). In other words, "select count(*) from places where id_extern>=id" must return 0 in your DB

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will need to reorder ids from the table.